# Nginx config can't reload. Have "bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)" errors

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, https

I tried installing an HTTPS certificate, and after banging my head against the wall for a few hours, I realized that Nginx is NOT picking up the changes I made in my site configuration files contained within `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

When I run `service nginx restart` it restarts fine. When I run `nginx -t` it says my syntax is OK and my config test is successful. However, when I run `service nginx reload` I get an error that says `reload: Not running`

When I look in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I have these errors.

```
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/08/29 16:04:40 [emerg] 14744#14744: still could not bind()
```

After Googling around, I ran across this command `netstat -plutn | grep 80` which gives me...

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14642/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      14642/nginx: worker
```

I have no idea what this really means, but reading around, it seems Nginx should NOT be running on port 80? Nginx is my webserver, don't I want it running on port 80?

Not sure how to proceed. I want Nginx to pick up the changes I made in my site config files with the `service nginx reload` command, and at the same time I'm hesitant to just copy/paste commands I find around the net since I have 10 websites hosted on this server.

Where am I going wrong? I have tried deleting the `default` file in my `sites-available` folder as some have suggested, but I just don't really understand what the problem is, and how to fix it.

Comment: Could be that it's already running and you're trying to run it again. Something like "ps -ef | grep nginx" will tell you if it's running already, but your netstat suggests it is. Try stopping and starting nginx, which I do with "service nginx restart". You can also use "nginx -s reload", as described here. http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html  . For further help post your nginx and site configurations.

Comment: I have run "service nginx restart" about 100 times now, my updated config is still not taking effect. Something is blocking my updated configs to be reloaded

Comment: This is why I asked for the ps. Instead of restart you need to stop it, ensure it's stilled with a kill command, then start it again, like the answer below says.

Comment: When I run the `ps` command right now I get [this](http://pastebin.com/LQpvF77G)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is fixed. As Tim said, I ran the `ps -ef | grep nginx` command and manually ran `kill PID` for all the processes. Then I ran `service nginx restart` and all worked well. When I then ran `service nginx reload` I did NOT get an error, and my HTTPS cert now works. Thanks Tim and dmourati for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your init script and the pid file location for nginx. You can manually kill nginx like so:

> sudo kill 14642

Then start nginx via the init script as follows:

> sudo service nginx start

From there, if you copy/paste your init script and nginx.conf file, I'm sure we can find the problem with the pid.

Comment: I see my PID value changing each time I kill it. When I run `netstat -plutn | grep 80` I can see the updated PID is 14839. When I then kill it with `kill 14839` and immediately re-run `netstat -plutn | grep 80` I can see I have a new PID, 14859.  My nginx.conf is [here](http://pastebin.com/CpMHhpry) and my `/etc/init.d/nginx` script is [here](http://pastebin.com/YnpHxngX)